# I have these two bags. Top one is mostly grays. Bottom mostly whites with blues and yellows and one gold piece

Tags: set-identification

I have these two bags.  Top one is mostly grays.  Bottom mostly whites with blues and yellows and one gold piece.  Would you know the set they go to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top bag appears to be from one of [these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10188-1) [two](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75159-1) Death Stars (almost the same set).

Based on this [search](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=2412b&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=85&itemNo2=4070&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=59&itemNo3=14769&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=5&in=S) for sets with these three parts:
[image: pt1] [image: pt2] [image: pt3]